# How to do an ALL() or ANY() on a documents sub array

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Just learning the ins and outs of CosmosDB. I have the following test documents in CosmosDB:

```
[
    {
        "matchingID":123,
        "many":{
            "meta":"some data",
            "items":[
                {
                    "matchingID":921
                },
                {
                    "matchingID":123
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "matchingID":1337,
        "many":{
            "meta":"some more data",
            "items":[
                {
                    "matchingID":1337
                },
                {
                    "matchingID":1337
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "matchingID":9001,
        "many":{
            "meta":"all the datas",
            "items":[
                {
                    "matchingID":42
                },
                {
                    "matchingID":5318008
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Please note these are test documents - the actual documents have many more properties in both the root item as well as the sub items. Each item has a subarray under `c.many.items`. This sub array has a property that may or may not match the one on it's root. What I'm hoping to achieve is to create a query that will allow me to return items where their subitems ALL match, and another query that will return what ANY of them match.

For example
`SELECT * FROM c WHERE ALL(c.many.items.matchingID) = c.matchingID` would return the second item, since all the subitem properties match on their parent:

```
 {
        "matchingID":1337,
        "many":{
            "meta":"some more data",
            "items":[
                {
                    "matchingID":1337
                },
                {
                    "matchingID":1337
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

`SELECT * FROM c WHERE ANY(c.many.items.matchingID) = c.matchingID` would return the first object, sicne at least one of the sub items matches on the property

```
    {
        "matchingID":123,
        "many":{
            "meta":"some data",
            "items":[
                {
                    "matchingID":921
                },
                {
                    "matchingID":123
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `SELECT * FROM c WHERE ANY(c.many.items.matchingID) = c.matchingID` should return the first and the second object.

- ANY

try this sql:

```
SELECT * FROM c where ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.many.items,{"matchingID":c.matchingID},true)
```

Here is the result:

```
 [
    {
        "matchingID": 123,
        "many": {
            "meta": "some data",
            "items": [
                {
                    "matchingID": 921
                },
                {
                    "matchingID": 123
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "matchingID": 1337,
        "many": {
            "meta": "some more data",
            "items": [
                {
                    "matchingID": 1337
                },
                {
                    "matchingID": 1337
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

- ALL

I can't do it just using a sql.So I query twice.

First sql(get the `matchingID` Array):

```
select value d.matchingID from (select c.matchingID,max(t.matchingID) as max,min(t.matchingID) as min from c join t in c.many.items group by c.matchingID) d where d.max = d.min and d.max = d.matchingID
```

By the way, If your `matchingID` is not unique, please add a unique property after `group by`,like `group by c.matchingID,c.id`

Second sql(get the object):

```
SELECT * FROM c where ARRAY_CONTAINS('first sql result',c.matchingID,true)
```

Hope these can help you.

---

**Update Answer:**

Here is my test udf:

```
function compareMatchID(matchingID,subArray){
    var result = subArray.every(function(a){
        return a.matchingID == matchingID;
    });
    return result;
}
```

Here is the sql:

```
SELECT * FROM c where udf.compareMatchID(c.matchingID,c.many.items)
```

This sql costs 4.4RUs with your example document.

Comment: Thanks. You're right, the ANY should have returned both objects in my example.

Testing these on my dataset, the ANY() solution seems relatively straightforward. it costs 16RUs. however, the ALL() solution seems really complicated - I can see what it's trying to do, but the at least on my dataset it's pretty poor in performance and the cost is > 1200 RU. I'll give this post a few more days to see if there's any other possible solutions, otherwise I may have to add a property  to my `many` object eg: `"any": true, "all": false` since this is all precalc'd, static data anyway

Comment: Alternatively, I'm wondering if it's possible to use a UDF for the ALL?

Comment: You can try it.But UDF do not have access to the context object,so you need to pass your documents to UDF,and then loop sub array and compare matchingID.I'm afraid that the performance of UDF may not be better and the cost is also expensive.I think you can deal with it by using code on the client-side better than using UDF.

Comment: I updated my answer and you can try it.It costs more Ru than `select * from c` with your example.If you don't want to add a property to your many object,you can get all data and deal with it by using code.